# CentOS 6.4 replace "CentOS 6.4" title during boot

Tags: centos, customization, boot

I would like to change the "CentOS 6.4" text which is displayed next to the boot status bar during boot with a custom text.

[image: Example of the boot sequence]

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

The solution for above query is achieved by Plymouth theme plugin. Change the default "text" theme and program you own customized theme as mentioned [here](http://theurbanpenguin.com/wp/?p=3227)

Answer (score 0):

A few years later... I ran into the same issue and unable to find doc's online. After reviewing source code in plymouth. The text that is displayed in this screen is extracted from the /etc/system-release file from BOTH the installed operating system and the initrd/initramfs file. If you make changes to both by editing the file and replacing and repackaging the initrd you will see the updated text.